# How to seek & commit when using custom (ConsumerAware) error handler?

Tags: kotlin, error-handling, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

**Situation**

I am trying to implement my custom error handler for a [Spring-Kafka](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka)(2.3.3.RELEASE) **batch** message listener. I have pretty bare bone configuration:

```
val factory = ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Int, String>()

factory.consumerFactory = kafkaConsumerFactory
factory.isBatchListener = true
factory.setBatchErrorHandler(MyErrorHandler())
```

Without any extra consumer configuration. Note that "Starting with version 2.3, the framework sets enable.auto.commit to false".

I am using a "consumer aware" `@KafkaListener` and my custom error handler also implement `ConsumerAwareBatchErrorHandler`.

In my error handler I use the `Consumer.seek(topicPartition, offset)` method to either seek to next or seek to current offset.

The problem is that whenever the error handler is invoked and I manually seek to some offset, the offset doesn't seem to be committed to Kafka. This is proven by the fact that after an application restart it polls the same (previously failed) records (even when the code seeks to next). 
What confuses me even more is that while the application is running, it does seem to use the `seek()`'ed offset and polls *new* records.

I've tried using different `AckMode`s, for example `MANUAL` or `MANUAL_IMMIDIATE`, but that does not change the observed behavior. Also the documentation says for these modes:

> MANUAL, and MANUAL_IMMEDIATE require the listener to be an AcknowledgingMessageListener or a BatchAcknowledgingMessageListener

which obviously I am not using.

If have already found a "fix", which is calling `consumer.commitSync()` after the `.seek()`, which seems to commit the offset immediately. This is also backed up by the logging:

`DEBUG 13784 --- [ntainer#2-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=kafka-retry-test] Committed offset 28 for partition test-retry-batch-custom-e-0`

**Question**

Why is just calling `consumer.seek(...)` not committing offsets to kafka and am I missing some critical configuration? Calling the `.commitSync()` seems like a hack and is not described in the documentation to be needed anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A seek does not commit the offset, it simply positions the current consumer at that point. You need to call `syncCommit` or `asyncCommit`.

However, starting with versionn 2.3.2 (current release is 2.3.4), you can return true from `isAckAfterHandle()`:

```
/**
 * Return true if the offset should be committed for a handled error (no exception
 * thrown).
 * @return true to commit.
 * @since 2.3.2
 */
default boolean isAckAfterHandle() {
    // TODO: Default true in the next release.
    return false;
}
```

and the container will do the commits for you.

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.3.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#error-handlers).

> Starting with version 2.3.2, these interfaces have a default method `isAckAfterHandle()` which is called by the container to determine whether the offset(s) should be committed if the error handler returns without throwing an exception. This returns false by default, for backwards compatibility. In most cases, however, we expect that the offset should be committed. For example, the SeekToCurrentErrorHandler returns true if a record is recovered (after any retries, if so configured). In a future release, we expect to change this default to true.

However, if you are using manual acks, your error handler must manually commit.

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for the clarification, missed this part in the documentation.I've confirmed that it works!

Comment: By the way, if you are interested in my custom batch error handler, I've created a demo project: https://github.com/MitchelNijdam-Rockstars/kafka-retry-demo where `ExtensiveCustomBatchErrorHandler.kt` is where this particular question was about.

Comment: Interesting; I hadn't considered sending a complete batch to the DLT but I guess that might be a valid scenario for some folks. Feel free to make a contribution to the framework, but it would have to be converted to Java, we can't force a runtime dependency on Kotlin.